# How to set list of required attributes in AngularJS Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, attributes

I have created AngularJS directive that requires HTML element to:
1) be a child of the form;
2) have 'conditional-value' attribute;

To accomplish this I created directive like this:

```
.directive('onFocusoutDoSomething', function () {
    return {
        require  : ['^?form', '^conditionalValue'],
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            // ... do something
            }
    }
})
```

But for some reason I get this Exception:
Controller 'conditionalValue', required by directive 'onFocusoutDoSomething', can't be found!

Camel case directive name and attributes are replaces with dash cases by AngularJS, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to create 'A' attribute type directive, it should be placed in scope{conditionalValue:'='} of directive or bindToController:{conditionalValue:'='}, not in require:{}, require is used for directive to directive communication.

If you have require in directive definition object, that directive is inheriting form parent directive mentioned in require field. for example if you have,

```
app.directive('tabSet',function(){
 //DDO
});
```

tabs directive can inherit the controller properties of tabSet directive.

```
app.directive('tabs',function(){
  return{
    require:'^tabSet'
  }
});
```